# Generators for Ideals in ring of multivariate Laurent Polynomials

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, local-rings, tropical-geometry

Consider the following problem:

Find an ideal $I \subset \mathbb{Q}[x^{\pm}_1,x^{\pm}_2,x^{\pm}_3]$ such that $I_{aff} \subset \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, x_3] = I \cap k[x_1, x_2, x_3]$ requires more generators than $I$, and the homogenenisation   $I_{proj} \in k[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]$ requires more generators than $I_{aff}$.

It is fairly straightforward to give an example of an ideal $I$ whose homogenenisation $I_{proj}$ requires more generators - take for example the ideal of the twisted cubic $I_{t}$ = $\langle x_2 - x^2_1, x_3 - x^3_1 \rangle$. However I'm stuck on how exactly to construct the ideal in the Laurent polynomial ring. One approach was to attempt to take the colon ideal

$\langle x_2 - x^2_1, x_3 - x^3_1 \rangle$ : $\langle x_1, x_2, x_3 \rangle$

which corresponds to deleting the origin of the twisted cubic, but this simply leaves me with an ideal containing three generators. I feel like I'm missing a key part of the understanding here, so if anyone could help I would be very grateful.

Regards

b_dobres